# Tesseract mixing up "1" and "7" despite training on exact font

Tags: tesseract

I am using tesseract to get text from an image, I am only interested in numbers. I have trained tesseract and created a new language that is the exact font in the image and the training data only included numbers. In the training data I also included every possible value that would be in an image, 1-5000 to be specific and also created a wordlist of these same values. However it still mixes up 1 and 7, as well as sometimes 3 and 8. Does anybody have any recommendations on whether I should retrain differently or do some processing on the image before giving it to tesseract?

Comment: Can edit to add sample image, tesseract command and output to help on the understanding of your problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure there are at least 20 instances of every character in the training texts you provide to tesseract. I give at least 6 pages of the same font to have a decent training sample size.

2.Tesseract Text Recognition also depends on the image quality. Check out possible preprocessing algorithms you can use: [Improve Quality of Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality)

3. Take a look at the number_dawg file. Modifying it can help recognising digits.